# How can I tell if a javascript object is an Image or a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, reflection, canvas

I have a class with a property that can be an Image (i.e. an IMG element) or a Canvas. When I serialize it to JSON, I need to convert this to a text string. If it is a Canvas, then I can call Canvas#toDataURL. But if it is an Image, I first need to draw it to a Canvas with Canvas#drawImage, then serialize that canvas with toDataURL.

So how do I determine if the object is a Canvas or an Image? (Since Canvas#drawImage is capable of accepting either Image or Canvas objects as an argument, there must be a way.)

I have seen that some programmers test for the existence of certain properties or functions to determine class, but I was wondering if there is a smarter way that won't break if the API presented by these objects changes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
function isImage(i) {
    return i instanceof HTMLImageElement;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a spoiled Java programmer who misses his reflection.

Answer (score 14):

If cross-window/frame compatibility is a concern you can check [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName):

```
var isImg = (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img');
```

Comment: Does this work for images that were created with new Image() and are not yet inserted in DOM?

Comment: @jayarjo: For sure. `(new Image()).nodeName.toLowerCase()` yields `"img"`.

Answer (score 11):

```
function isCanvas(i) {
    return i instanceof HTMLCanvasElement;
}
```

Comment: One sentence of explanation? Just one? Please?